# Node js Gmail SMTP Auth Error (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: node.js, email, smtp

I'm facing this error while sending email with Node.js, need any setting in server (Ubuntu 14.04) for send email or it's Google Authentication error.

[image: node js email error]

Comment: From your google account, Go to http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha & also allow `Less Secure Apps` from security menu

Comment: You are really genius man, Thankew so much, it worked

Comment: Happy to help :)